# Cypress - Create a new 'it' on each loop cycle

Tags: javascript, loops, cypress

I'm automating the completion of a questionnaire via Cypress using fixtures. I need to create a new `IT` statement on each iteration of a loop running as currently if 1 set fails in the loop, then the rest of the dataset does not run.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
context('Questionnaire Completion', () => {
    Cypress.Cookies.debug(true);
    
    beforeEach(function() {
        cy.fixture('data_set_4').then((testdata) => {
            this.data = testdata
        });
    });

        describe ('I will complete the form with each entry in the data set', function() {
            
            it ('I will complete the form with each entry in the data set', function() {
                
                for (let i = 0; i < this.data.testdata.length ; i++) {

                    participantcreation(this.data.testdata[i].DataEntry);
    
                        //I will enter a name and click Next
                        Name(this.data.testdata[i].DataEntry);

                        for (let j = 1; j < 31 ; j++) {
                            let answer = this.data.testdata[i]['Q' + j] - 1;
                                cy.get('#questionnaire_question_'+j+'_'+answer).click({ force: true });

                }
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about what is being asked here but if you wish to create multiple 'its' depending on what you need you can just put it in a loop

```js
describe('Tests', () => {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        it(`Test ${i}`, () => {
            cy.wait(200)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately that won't work in this instance as if I'm right when you refer to a fixture (datasets) it needs to be in an 'it'. It doesn't work as I'm refering the fixture data in the initial loop (I can't change this as the loop is to last as long as the amount of data in the fixture)